# Zabbix UserParameters have problems with parenthesis?

Tags: zabbix

I'd like to issue that command as *UserParameter* in zabbix 3.0

```
[ "$((exit 1 || echo 'col1 -1') | awk '{print $2}')" == 0 ]  && echo OK || echo FAILED
# alternatively
test "$((exit 1 || echo 'col1 -1') | awk '{print $2}')" == 0  && echo OK || echo FAILED
```

Firing this on bash shell works, perfectly (returning FAILED), but zabbix-agent return syntax error:

```
$ sudo -u zabbix zabbix_agentd -t testparam
testparam   [t|sh: 1: Syntax error: Missing '))']
```

Setting *UnsafeUserParameters* has no effect.

How to get this running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because Zabbix executes user parameters using `/bin/sh`, not `/bin/bash`. So you can either try to adapt your command to work with `/bin/sh` or prefix it with `/bin/bash`, like so:

```
UserParameter=testparam,/bin/bash -c '...'
```

Alternatively, you may wish to try rewriting your command in a style similar to this:

```
UserParameter=testparam,var=`exit 1 || echo 'col1 -1'`; test "`echo $var | awk '{ print $2 }'`" = 0 && echo OK || echo FAILED
```

Comment: Couldn't get this running neither using `/bin/bash -c '...'`  nor `/bin/bash -c "..."` (I've also escaped quotation marks).

Comment: I have updated the answer with an alternative suggestion.

Comment: The rewritten command works